# calculation in Javascript (using double notation technique)

Tags: javascript

Hello guys i trying to get the percentage of different values using javascript specifically using the double notation technique but am getting an invalid syntax on this line
 var EFG =  Response_E41 – (- Response_E43) – (- Response_E44) ; but i believe its correct, what could be wrong?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPercentage(){

            var grade = "";  //declare a variable for grade
            var  result="";  //declare a variable for result

            //read the marks
            var Response_B4 = document.getElementByName('Response_B4').value;
            var Response_C4 = document.getElementByName('Response_C4').value;
            var Response_D4 = document.getElementByName('Response_D4').value;
            var Response_E41 = document.getElementByName('Response_E41').value;
            var Response_E43 = document.getElementByName('Response_E43').value;
            var Response_E44 = document.getElementByName('Response_E44').value;



            //calculate the total marks (using double notation technique)
             var BCD = Response_B4 - (- Response_C4) - (- Response_D4);
             var EFG =  Response_E41 – (- Response_E43) – (- Response_E44) ;

            //get the average marks
            var averageMarks = BCD / EFG;


 //display the results
document.getElementById('overall').value = averageMarks;

} //end of function getpercentage

</script>
```

Comment: Some of those dashes are en-dashes, not minus signs. Delete the row and re-write it from scratch.

Comment: You have *lots* of issues, but the first one is that you put HTML (`<script>`) in the box marked "JavaScript". The second is that you forgot to include any HTML in the HTML box (like the inputs you are trying to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Corrected :

```js
var getPercentage = () => {

            var grade = "",  //declare a variable for grade
                result="";  //declare a variable for result

            //read the marks
            var Response_B4 = document.getElementByName('Response_B4').value;
            var Response_C4 = document.getElementByName('Response_C4').value;
            var Response_D4 = document.getElementByName('Response_D4').value;
            var Response_E41 = document.getElementByName('Response_E41').value;
            var Response_E43 = document.getElementByName('Response_E43').value;
            var Response_E44 = document.getElementByName('Response_E44').value;



            //calculate the total marks (using double notation technique)
            // Updated : EFG variable was using dash and not a minus sign
             var BCD = Response_B4 - (- Response_C4) - (- Response_D4);
             var EFG = Response_E41 - (-Response_E43) - (-Response_E44) ;

            //get the average marks
            var averageMarks = BCD / EFG;


 //display the results
document.getElementById('overall').value = averageMarks;

} //end of function getpercentage
```

---

## Reason :

- You were using dashes instead of minus signs (causing the error)

---